# Joint PDF (probability density functions) of two correlated (non-independent) random varaiables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

If X and Y are correlated exponential Random variables and they are no longer independent(they are Correlated now)  how can I find joint PDF of X and Y ?  If they are independent I have to just multiply their PDFs to get joint PDF but now what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in general know the joint PDF from the marginals. That loss of information is fundamentally *what* makes them correlated. Formally, we can see this by noticing:

$$
P(A, B) = P(A|B) P(B) \neq P(A)P(B)
$$

So we need the quantity $P(A|B)$, but if all we have is $P(A)$ we're out of luck.

Comment: I am definitely out of luck here Siddharth, however I found something

F. Downton, “Bivariate exponential distributions in reliability theory,”
J. Royal Statistical Soc., B, vol. 32, pp. 408–417, 1970.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I really don't know whether I can mention you or not, But if yes kindly look into this